# Unknown column "has" in 'where clause

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I am using laravel 5.7

When I use `whereHas` to check a relation's existence, I face with `Unknown column "has" in 'where clause` Error! Why?

this is my code:

```php
$query->whereHas('departures', function ( $query) {
    $query->whereBetween('depart_date', [date($this->data['departFrom_date']), date($this->data['departTo_date'])]);
});
```

and this is my model part:

```php
    public function departures()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(CruiseSailingDepartures::class);
    }
```

**Update:**

The query was started with:

```php
$query = DB::table('table_name');
```

Comment: Can you please sure the full query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put the foreign key and local key in relationship.

```
public function departures()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Model\CruiseSailingDepartures','foreign_key','local_key');
}

$res = BaseModel::find($id);
foreach($res->departures as $departures)
{
  echo $departures->name; //whatever field you have in CruiseSailingDepartures table
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```php
$model = YourModel::with('departures')->whereHas('departures', function($query) use ($this) {
    $query->whereBetween('depart_date', [date($this->data['departFrom_date']), date($this->data['departTo_date'])]);
})->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found my problem, I was using `DB::table('tablename')` instead of using the Model (`TableName:: ...`)

Thanks for all answers